# Multiple registrations of unauthorized users

Tags: wordpress

Daily I am receiving several registrations of users with the role of "Customer" on my site. This has been going on for months and I just erase it, but it started to bother me because now there are many. How do I disable this and prevent new users from being registered without proper permission?

See what they look like: [image]

I have already disabled plugins, installed a firewall, scanned for viruses and nothing resolved.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-captcha-in-wordpress-login-and-registration-form/) help?

Comment: registration of new users is already disabled. So this solution does not work. Any other suggestions?